# Drupal amazon s3 image styles not generated

Tags: 7, proxies

My server configuration:

`drupal 7 + multisite, nginx + varnish` and `Amazon s3` storage for image assets.
I have my website images in **amazon s3** storage. I can able to upload the images via drupal into amazon s3. Also drupal creates the different types of image styles for s3 images.

After I have pointed my **DNS** to live domain name `www.example.com`, the image styles are not creating. If I try load the image src in browser url `www.example.com/system/files/styles/mystyle/s3/image.jpg`, the server says **"Access Denied"**.

But the image styles are creating in `DNS url` which is provide by hosting provider.
`myserver001.hosting.com/system/files/styles/mystyle/s3/image.jpg`

Do I need to configure anything in **nginx** server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not say how you are connecting to Amazon S3. What module are you using?

Comment: I am using amazons3 module

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I cannot assist. I am the maintainer of Storage API. I didn't know if you were using my module.

Comment: @Brady do i need to hack core to use Storage API? I really want to use S3 but do not want to hack core which is required by Amazon S3 module

Comment: @LeeWoodman no hacking required!